# Remove `CHAPTER 0.' from header in frontmatter chapters with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

As the title says. The heading on the page following the Abstract looks like this:

> `CHAPTER 0. ABSTRACT`

How can I remove the unnecessary Chapter number from the headings in the frontmatter?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Abstract}
Why does it say ``Chapter 0.'' on the next page?
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `fancy` uses the ruled header style, with `\thechapter` etc. information. Since `frontmatter` disables the numbering, the chapter number is still `0`. Either redefine the headings or apply `\pagestyle{fancy}` after the abstract chapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fancyhdr` package provides, by default, the definition of `\chaptermark` used in `report.cls` when `\pagestyle{headings}` is in force.

The `book` class instead has a check for `\if@mainmatter`:

```
  \def\ps@headings{%
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
      \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
```

So you should supplement your code with the right definition. There's still a small problem, in that the pages of the table of contents will have *two* “CONTENTS” in the header, because `\tableofcontents` uses `\@mkboth`; you can fix it by redefining it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
      \fi
    \fi
    #1}}{}%
}
\renewcommand\@mkboth[2]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\makeatother

\frontmatter
\chapter{Abstract}
Why does it say ``Chapter 0.'' on the next page?
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\end{document}
```