# change chaptermark in combination with frontmatter, mainmatter

Tags: header-footer, book-design

I am trying to change the `chaptermark` (and `sectionmark`) in my book class document. I want to disable uppercase and to not display `\chaptername`.

I found some explanations on a [wiki page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers). According to this manual the following command will do the job.

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
```

However, for chapters in `\frontmatter` this produces unwanted headers with 0. This can be fixed with an if statement. The problem I have is that for `\tableofcontents` I still get an uppercase `CONTENTS` in the header and the same goes for the bibliography.

Here a minimal example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Here we go}
Random text

\appendix
\chapter{some things you better know}

\backmatter
\end{document}
```

I found attempts [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120603/customize-chaptermark-for-mainmatter) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290400/remove-chapter-0-from-header-in-frontmatter-chapters-with-fancyhdr) on this site, but since in most mathbooks it is standard to not use uppercase I am surprised that there is no easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you request. The issue with `\tableofcontents` is that it calls `\markboth` directly with fixed arguments. So we have to change `\chaptermark` and additionally patch `\tableofcontents`.

The same patch would be necessary for `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` as well, so place two calls to `\patchcmd` for those as well if you intend to use them.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]
  {%
    \markboth
      {%
        \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \thechapter . \ 
          \fi
        \fi
        #1%
      }{}%
  }
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{%
  \markright{% <- this would produce a space without the %
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth > \z@
    \thesection. \ % <- the spacing in the original definition
    \fi
    #1}% <- this would produce a space without the %
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% there are two \MakeUppercase commands contained in \tableofcontents, we remove
% both
\patchcmd\tableofcontents{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{\ERROR}
\patchcmd\tableofcontents{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{\ERROR}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Here we go}
Random text

\appendix
\chapter{some things you better know}

\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this does the job. Nevertheless, I wonder why this very common task is so hard and needs so much pure TeX knowledge. For example I have no idea what `\m@ne` is.
I tried to do the same with the bibliography, but it seems like it is not trivial to finde the correct command, because `\bibliography` doesn't seem to work. Can you tell me which command is for the bibliography?

Comment: I added the solution for sections to your answer I just hacked some code I found. I can only guess why its work. Maybe you can check, if there are no mistakes. At least it works in my environment.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek you don't show any code, so how should I check? `\m@ne` is just a faster version of saying `-1`. The macro `\bibliography` might depend on used packages, so without an MWE showing your usage of that I can't really help.

Comment: Oh, forget about the "you show no code" thingy, just saw the edit, sorry. Your code has a few superfluous spaces, I'll edit it in my answer.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek it is hard to change these things (without additional packages) because the base classes of LaTeX are intended as just that: A base. You can load additional packages to add functionality or change the layout, or you use a more versatile and easier to customize class (the KOMA script classes or `memoir` come to mind). The thing about LaTeX is that much of what you want was already wanted by someone else, and chances are good that there is a package or dedicated class for it.

Comment: I don't use any special package for the bibliography, at least not that I know. I use
`\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{bibfile}{}`
If this is not enough to say what is to do, I will just open another question.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek for that you need to patch `\thebibliography` (same patch as above, two times, so `\patchcmd\thebibliography{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{\ERROR}` two times).

Comment: Thanks, this works. I am wondering where would I find such information? Because I tried to look via internet search engines, but I couldn't find \thebibliography. Is there a .sty file for the book class locally on my machine where I can look up the definition of `\chaptermark` and such things?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek you can run the following on the terminal: `latexdef -c book chaptermark`, that prints the definition. Also, `book.cls` would be the file (the document classes are not styles but `.cls` files). And `thebibliography` is an environment, not a macro, but since environments in LaTeX use `\<environment-name>` for the start part and `\end<environment-name>` for the end part you can patch those to change the behaviour of an environment.